# what are the direct real life applications of general relativity and quantum physics

Tags: general-relativity

What are the direct real life applications of general relativity other than nuclear technology?

What I meant was, was there any technology developed based on general relativity that can benefit mankind today?

Secondly, are there any adverse effects quantum technology today?

Comment: Nuclear technology is not based in general relativity, but rather in quantum mechanics. An example of general relativity applied to technology is GPS tracking. General relativity deals with gravity and its effects on space-time and it has to be taken into account to make the GPS precise.  What do you mean by adverse effects of quantum technology? Most (if not all) of our modern electronic devises are based  on quantum mechanics.

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70541/ but in general I see this as a make-a-list question and not suited to the site.

Comment: Indeed, with a bit of training, it becomes hard to see anything that's *not* quantum. Sure Newtonian mechanics works fine for ordinary macroscopic motions, but the properties of materials themselves are entirely quantum in origin: the fact that matter is stable and doesn't all collapse to a point, the fact that temperatures above absolute zero are possible without destroying everything with intense radiation, the fact that atomic structure exists which makes chemistry possible, and electrical conductivity in metals, and ferromagnetism and on and on and on...